# Finding the shortest distance between a surface specified by vertices and a point

Tags: geometry

I want to determine the point on a triangular surface which is the shortest distance from a point $a = (-2, -40, -50)$.

The triangle is specified by its three vertex coordinates:

$P_1 = (-10, 20, 30)$

$P_2 = (15, 25, 25)$

$P_3 = (5, -20, 50)$

If I derive an equation for the surface I know that the normal vector to the surface at the point with the shortest distance will be co-linear to the vector between this point and $a$. Any advice as to deriving this equation or better methods would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

To get a normal vector to the plane, first calculate two vectors in the plane:
$$
u=P_2-P_1=(25,5,-5)^t\\
v=P_3-P_1=(15,-40,20)^t
$$
We can get a normal vector to these vectors by taking the cross product (but first I divide both vectors by $5$ to make calculations easier):
$$
a=\frac 15 u=(5,1,-1)^t\\
b=\frac 15 v=(3,-8,4)^t\\
n=a\times b=(1\cdot 4--1\cdot -8,-1\cdot 3-4\cdot 5,5\cdot -8-3\cdot 1)^t\\
=(-4,-23,-43)^t
$$
Testing shows that this vector is normal to $u$ and $v$ indeed.

To get the point in the plane with the shortest distance to $a$, intersect the line
$$
(-2,-40,-50)^t+\lambda n
$$
with the plane
$$
P_1+\alpha(P_2-P_1)+\beta(P_3-P_1)
$$